# How can I position the colorbar better?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I'm trying to align the right edge of both plots and have the colorbar hanging to the right. This is what I have:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def F(x, y):
    u = x
    v = y
    return u, v

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8), tight_layout=True)
ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1, 1, 10), np.linspace(-1, 1, 10))
u, v = F(x, y)
vres = np.sqrt(u ** 2 + v ** 2)
vector_field = ax1.quiver(x, y, u, v, vres)

fig.colorbar(vector_field, ax=ax1)

plt.show()
```

And this is what I got:

[image: figure]

I've read the colorbar doc but couldn't find what I wanted, can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This docs page](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/colorbar_placement.html) seems interesting.

Comment: I've seen that too, but didn't find exactly what I wanted. Very close though!

Answer (score 0):

Updated solution:

You can actually just add another colorbar to your second subplot and make it not visible, like this.
`fig.colorbar(vector_field, ax=ax2).ax.set_visible(False)`

Complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def F(x, y):
    u = x
    v = y
    return u, v
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8), tight_layout=True)
ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1, 1, 10), np.linspace(-1, 1, 10))
u, v = F(x, y)
vres = np.sqrt(u ** 2 + v ** 2)
vector_field = ax1.quiver(x, y, u, v, vres)
fig.colorbar(vector_field, ax=ax1)
fig.colorbar(vector_field, ax=ax2).ax.set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

Old solution with different result:

I did not expext this to work, but is this what you need?

ax from colorbar can actually take a list of axes , not only one: `fig.colorbar(vector_field, ax=[ax1, ax2])`. You will also have to remove the tight_layout though...`tight_layout=False`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def F(x, y):
    u = x
    v = y
    return u, v
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8), tight_layout=False)
ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1, 1, 10), np.linspace(-1, 1, 10))
u, v = F(x, y)
vres = np.sqrt(u ** 2 + v ** 2)
vector_field = ax1.quiver(x, y, u, v, vres)
fig.colorbar(vector_field, ax=[ax1, ax2])
plt.show()
```

Comment: I just updated the solution, is it that what you wanted?

Comment: Hmm, I kind of wwanted the colorbar align justo with the first plot. stackoverflow.com/questions/13310594/positioning-the-colorbar 
One of the answers to this similar questions suggests: 
`cbaxes = fig.add_axes([0.8, 0.1, 0.03, 0.8]) `
`cb = plt.colorbar(ax1, cax = cbaxes)`
but I couln't get it to work

Comment: I had that idea one minute ago and was just about to search if it is possible to set something invisible, haha

That turned out great!!! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Just so if you're curious, this is what I'm working on: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PCi1Fm4_hruh97mN_pFQ8dThKpGCN-u0/view?usp=sharing)